# How to allocate a value that changes while execution in vim (lightline plugin)?

Tags: vim, powerline, vim-powerline

I'm hacking on the [lightline](https://github.com/itchyny/lightline.vim) plugin of vim (downloaded version). I can modify the colors of each themes. I did something that works well in the powerline.vim scheme (path : `~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/lightline/autoload/lightline/colorscheme/powerline.vim`)

Now I want the colortheme to change while I'm in vim. I added this code in the begining of powerline.vim :

```
10    let s:BSsplitscolor = "'darkestgreen', 'brightgreen'"
11    if g:BSsplitsbool == "1"
12            let s:BSsplitscolor = "'gray4', 'brightorange'"
13    endif
14
15    " ============================== NOTE: below : already there
16
17    let s:p = {'normal': {}, 'inactive': {}, 'insert': {}, 'replace': {}, 'visual': {}, 'tabline': {}}
18    let s:p.normal.left = [ [s:BSsplitscolor, 'bold'], ['white', 'gray4'] ]
```

Here `s:BSsplitscolor` contains the colors I want : it's either `'gray4', 'brightorange'` if `g:BSsplitsbool` equals `1` or `'darkestgreen', 'brightgreen'` if not. It's `g:BSsplitsbool` that changes.

Now the problem is at the 16th line : when I add `s:BSsplitscolor` after `[ [`, I get these errors when I restart vim (translate from french) :

```
    Error detected while treating functionlightline#update[5]..lightline#colorscheme[18]..lightline#highlight :
    line   18 :
    E254: can not allocate color darkestgreen
    E416: missing '=' : , 'brightgreen' guibg=bold ctermfg=0 ctermbg=0
    Error detected while treating function lightline#update :
    line    5 :
    E171: missing :endif
```

I think I'm missing something... I'm not so good at vim scripting : I can do an if instruction, remap, and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

First, the solution:

```
let s:BSsplitscolor = ['darkestgreen', 'brightgreen']
[...]
let s:p.normal.left = [ s:BSsplitscolor + ['bold'], ['white', 'gray4'] ]
```

Second, the explanation:

You are trying to build a list of three items:

```
['darkestgreen', 'brightgreen', 'bold']
```

out of a string that vaguely looks like a list:

```
"'darkestgreen', 'brightgreen'"
```

and a list with a single string:

```
['bold']
```

by inserting that string in that list:

```
[ s:BSsplitscolor, 'bold']
```

which gives you this monstrosity:

```
['''darkestgreen'', ''brightgreen''', 'bold']
```

which is a list of two items, not at all what you are trying to build. I'm not aware of a scripting language where something like that could be expected to work.

The actual solution is to make `s:BSsplitscolor` a list:

```
let s:BSsplitscolor = ['darkestgreen', 'brightgreen']
```

and merge it with `['bold']`. This can be done in several ways. With `:help expr-+`:

```
let s:p.normal.left = [ s:BSsplitscolor + ['bold'], ['white', 'gray4'] ]
```

or with `:help extend()`:

```
let s:p.normal.left = [ extend(s:BSsplitscolor, ['bold']), ['white', 'gray4'] ]
```